# bash shell script; bc math error

Tags: bash, shell, math, bc

I am a beginner of bash shell scripting. I am using bc for float type data calculation, but I got the following error. I have tried to search this on-line, but wasn't able to solve this. My simplified code and error are attached below.

```
aa=1270000000.000000
bb=14000000
cc=-5245200.55453439363590374313
dd=4666666.66666666666666666666
ee=$(echo "$aa-$bb/2-$cc+2.5*$dd" | bc -l)
```

(standard_in) 1: syntax error

The strange thing is that, the following code seems work.

```
aa=1.222
bb=2
cc=3.999
dd=4.222222
ee=$(echo "$aa-$bb/2-$cc+2.5*$dd" | bc -l)
```

This is weird, but I don't know how this happen. Does anyone have any idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've always liked polish notation. `ee=$(dc -e "$aa $bb 2 / - $cc - 2.5 $dd * + p")`.

Answer (score 2):

`bc's` parser treats adjacent negative signs as the decrement operator; `3--3` is not the same as `3 - -3` or `3-(-3)`. You need to adjust the argument to `echo` accordingly, to accomodate a value of `cc` that begins with a `-`.

```
ee=$(echo "$aa-$bb/2-($cc)+2.5*$dd" | bc -l)
```

or

```
ee=$(echo "$aa - $bb / 2 - $cc + 2.5 * $dd" | bc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

bc needs spaces between operators.

```
aa=1270000000.000000
bb=14000000
cc=-5245200.55453439363590374313
dd=4666666.66666666666666666666
ee=$(echo "$aa - $bb / 2 - $cc + 2.5 * $dd" | bc -l)
```

Comment: This is not generally correct. It only needs spaces to tell `1--2` apart from `1-(-2)`.